# JooQ: Fluent record init and save

Tags: sql, jooq

Is it possible to init and save a record via Fluent model in JooQ?

I know you can generate fluent setters, but when you save the record, it returns an "int" so something like this will not work:

```
var resultRecord = dslContext
    .newRecord(TBL1)
    .setField1("Hello")
    .setField2("World")
    .store();
```

Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### No such method

There's no such method in jOOQ. For ages, the interesting bit of information when storing something to the database is the update count. While it would have been interesting (not just in jOOQ, but also in JDBC), to return an object that can contain much more context, that's not how things have been, and I don't think such a change would pull its weight.

#### Write your own utilities

You can write a utility like this:

```java
static <R extends UpdatableRecord<R>> store(R r) {
    r.store();
    return r;
}
```

And now use it like this:

```java
var resultRecord = store(dslContext
    .newRecord(TBL1)
    .setField1("Hello")
    .setField2("World")
);
```

Or even more generic:

```java
static <T> with(T t, Consumer<? super T> consumer) {
    consumer.accept(t);
    return r;
}
```

And then:

```java
var resultRecord = with(dslContext
    .newRecord(TBL1)
    .setField1("Hello")
    .setField2("World"),
    r -> r.store()
);
```

#### Use `INSERT .. RETURNING`

In a way, this is equivalent and does what you're looking for:

```java
var resultRecord =
dslContext.insertInto(TBL)
          .set(TBL.FIELD1, "Hello")
          .set(TBL.FIELD2, "World")
          .returning()
          .fetchOne();
```

There's more data transfer in this approach, as all the column values are being returned back from the database, which is probably unnecessary in your case. But it is an option, especially if you *want to* fetch identity / default values anyway.

#### Other languages

In other languages (e.g. kotlin), such methods are offered out of the box, e.g. [`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html)